# Length of the objects in Factory in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 10 students and their ranking data at Service.js. I want User to select a ranking range, then I will show them the relative student info based on their rank range. For example, if they select from rank 2 to rank 5, they will only see the student info for ranks 2 to 5.

Since I only have 10 students in my database, I want to limit the lowest rank to 10 in the input. Thereby, I need the length of my data(object) in Service.js (backend) to return to the html(Front).

---

**Code has been updated.**

My service.js is in below:

```
(function(angular){
angular.module('Service', [])
.factory('ServiceFun', function(){
  var Objects = [
    {rank: 1,  name: 'id1'},
    {rank: 2,  name: 'id2'},
    {rank: 3,  name: 'id3'},];     
 var len = function (){
    len = 0;
    for (var i in Objects){
    if (Objects.hasOwnProperty(i)){
        len++;}
    };
    return len; 
 };
 return{Objects: Objects,
       len : len,};
});
})(window.angular)
```

my Controller.js is in below:

```
(function(angular) {
angular.module('PModule', ['Service'])
.controller('BetweenController', ['ServiceFun', function(ServiceFun) {
  this.high = 3;
  this.low = 1;
  this.Objects = ServiceFun.Objects;
  this.count =  function count(){
      return ServiceFun.len;       
  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

my main part of html for calling Controller is in below:

```
<body data-ng-app="PModule">
<div data-ng-controller="BetweenController as value">  
<div>  
<span>the highest ranking which you expected</span>
<input type="number" min ="1" data-ng-model="value.low" required>
<br/>
<span>the lowest ranking which you expected</span>
<input type="number" min ="1" max = "value.count()" data-ng-model="value.high"   required>
<div><h3>Show selected table</h3>
<table class="ranking">
<tr>
  <th>Rank</th>
  <th>Number</th>
</tr>
<tr data-ng-repeat="c in value.Objects" data-ng-if=" c.rank > value.low-1 && c.rank < value.high+1">
  <td>{{c.rank}}</td>
  <td>{{c.name}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>      

</div>
</div>
</body>
```

---

**My previous question text is here:**

I am using Angular JS to ask user to input the lowest rank and highest rank, then I will show them the relative data which is in their selected range. Of course, the lowest rank number which is allowed to input should be limited by my lowest rank in my database (the length of the database). Here comes the problem!

I hard coded some data (objects/arrays) in the Service. I want to pass the length of this objects in the Service to my Controller. Then in my View (html), I can use this information as my max input number (lowest rank number) by getting it from Controller. But it did not work.

I tried another simpler way as well such as "this.count = ServiceFun.Objects.length" in the Controller, but it did not work as well.

I read someone answered similar question before that using $scope.$watch; But in my case, I do not have $scope and data is in the Service. I also did not find $watch as well in my version of AngularJS 1.5.7.

Comment: What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: It will return the data inform ranked between the user selected range. I did not include that part of html code inside my question. Maybe I should. I will see if I can change it now.

Comment: You're still not telling what the problem is. What are you doing, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? I expect your question to contain something like: *I enter 12 in the first input field and 54 in te second, and I expect the table to show "Hello" in the first row and "Goodbye" in the second, but instead it displays "Hi" and "Bye", and I also get this error in the console*. See? Something that explains the problem, instead of forcing us to guess what your intention is and what the problem is.

Comment: OK, I guess I did not explain it clearly. Let us take an example that I have 10 students ranked from 1 to 10. I want User to select the highest and lowest rank, then the User can see the student's information between these two rank. For example User want to see the students' info ranked between 2 and 5, Then I expect the outcome table show like this: rank 2, Jim; rank 3, Tom; rank 4, Judy; rank 5, Sam. Of course, totally I only have 10 students. So when the User inputs the lowest rank which he wants to see. I want the lowest rank has been limited to 10 since I only have 10 students.

Comment: I hope that helped to myself more clear :-) I will appreciate if you can help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(angular) {
angular.module('PModule', ['Service'])
.controller('BetweenController', ['ServiceFun', function(ServiceFun) {
  this.high = 3;
  this.low = 1;
  this.Objects = ServiceFun.Objects;
  this.count = ServiceFun.len;       
  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

**Objects not Objcts**

Comment: I had a close look at it again and tried multiple ways but I still could not make it work. But I think at least you point me a good direction. I highly appreciate that.

Comment: I tried it multiple ways again this morning. So far I still could not make it work. But I think at least you pointed me a good direction. I highly appreciate that. Firstly, I tried "object.keys().length" in my Service.js. the whole code can't recognise it at all. I guess it is because it is in Service.js not in the Font (html). Secondly, I thought maybe I should hard code the count function to count its properties by using loop in Service.js. It did not work as well. The improvement was that at least the whole programming recognised it but it just could not get that length info which I need.

Comment: Thirdly, I wrapped it as a function in the Controller.js and Service.js. It still does not work as well. I am quite desperate now. Any other ways you would suggest me to try? All your help are highly appreciated!